# v-calendar event for previous and next header button

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, calendar

Is there a way to get the event when clicking previous and next button using v-calendar datepicker?

References:

- https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar-docs/blob/master/api.md
- https://vcalendar.netlify.app/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `update:from-page` event. The `page` parameter is passed that allows you to get meaningful data about what month was navigated to.

https://vcalendar.io/api/v2.0/calendar.html#update-from-page

Comment: How would I capture the page event in version 3 of your excellent Calendar control?